# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation again won't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I create a UIView and set it's layer's contents a image. And I added a tap gesture to this view. When I tap the view, I want it to rotate 180 degree, and when I click close button, I want it to rotate to it's original degree. But it won't work when I try to rotate it back.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menuArray"];
    self.menuView.layer.contents = (__bridge id)image.CGImage;

    self.menuView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap)];
    [self.menuView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
//rotate it 180 degree
- (void)tap
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.menuView.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
//rotate it back. this won't work. I have change the value from M_PI to M_PI_2, M_PI_4. it's not working.
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.menuView.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work as 'rotate by', but as 'rotate to', so using 0 should suffice to return it to original orientation. To 'rotate by' you'd need to concatenate transforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To undo an affineTransorm you should set it to the constant affineTransformIdentity , which is tranform of nil so to speak, a matrix of all zeros..

So in your second method where you want to rotate back set `self.menuView.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`

Comment: This is the beauty of working with transforms, one position remains 'home', you only need the one to go 'away from home' in this case the first rotation.  The second is always 'go home' as in the answer above.